# Element Array + 1 value

Tags: javascript

Having trouble adding a value to an element array.
An example of what I currently have.

```
array[1] current example is value of 10
var total = array[1] + 1; // result is 101
```

I need total to be 11, I also tried the bellow example, same thing.

```
var total = array[1].toString() + 1; // result 101
```

Comment: `var total = +array[1] + 1;`

Comment: Using `.toString()` is the opposite of what you need, because your array appears to contain strings already - is there a reason you didn't populate it with numbers rather than strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to Number before the addition otherwise, string concatenation will happen.

```
var total = +array[1] + 1;
```

Refer : [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I'll approve the message in 10min.

Comment: Can you explain how an `+` unary operator converts the `string` to `Number`?

Comment: I did try to find an answer before posting. ^ the above question might be useful for me too. Thanks again.

Comment: @haim770 +a ===Number(a), so it creates a number (primitive type, not a Number

Answer (score 1):

10 must be in string format, Use `parseInt` or `Uniary_plus` to convert it to number

```
var array = ['10'];
var total = parseInt(array[0],10) + 1;
alert(total)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/62k4081j/1/)